# Multiple DataFrame values

Tags: r

I have 12 dataframes, and they have common and different columns. I want to find the mean value for those common cells (same col&row) and replace that mean value in a final dataframe, and leave the different ones. How can I do this in R? HELP

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on SO. You should provide reproducible data and code and the expected output.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.